# Why does iOS 9 get bricked when reset to 1970?

Tags: ios

iOS 8/9 will get bricked if you set your date back too far. If someone could explain how exactly this happens, I would love to know.

Comment: Why would you ever want or need to set the current date to 1970?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some time zones, setting the date to 1 Jan 1970 will set the internal clock to a number less than zero, as the time is stored in GMT (as the number of seconds since midnight on that date) and then the offset is applied before display. In other time zones, setting the clock will result in a positive time value. Best guess is that this is triggered by having the time value less than zero.

This behaviour can be replicated by creating an NPT server on a network and injecting it to multiples devices. If the time returned to the device is negative, the device will crash.

Comment: That sounds a very plausible explanation. Still I don't see any good reason why someone would want to do that - unless they are hitchhiking in time...

Comment: No idea why, but just Google 'iOS 9 1970 bug' for a slew of related results.

Comment: I fell for this because someone on reddit (never trust the internet) said that resetting it back to 1970 would give a classic macintosh theme. http://i.imgur.com/mnfsKzF.png